# Redirecting different domains to your main site

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

My main domain is `widget.example` (for example), but I want to buy:

> `widget-dragon.example`
> `widget-killer.example`

and on and on
and redirect (301) to my main domain - `widget.example`, is this considered as a violation of SEO rules. Is it bad for business?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not bad for business and it is not bad SEO if all you do is a 301 redirect when you hit any of the other domains. Google even considers that a good thing because you are essentially telling them that those other domains are also just owned by you.

Tons of major sites do this already like American Airlines, `americanairlines.com` redirects to their main site (`aa.com`), and `bn.com` redirects to Barnes and Nobles main website. Some sites even own common misspellings and do 301 redirects from those domains just to make sure if you mistype the domain you still find them.

Where you can run into issues is when you create content at `widget-dragon.example` that is a duplicate of a page on `widget.example` and add links to it that go to the duplicate content page on `widget.example`.

One last thing to do is make sure your 301 is setup properly by using a tool to confirm your redirect is a 301 and has all of the proper header info it needs.

Comment: Alternate domain names that redirect have no positive SEO effect in my experience.  I wouldn't say that "Google even considers that a good thing."  I would say that Google completely ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a huge company with unlimited resources, like American Airlines?

Are you a company with a bland Acme-style name that's easily mistaken for a hundred other companies?

If no, buying a bunch of domains just to redirect them to your site sounds excessive and like a waste of money. Put those resources into creating great content.

Comment: thanks, that is in addition. we are not spending money on it, we own these domains and we own our own hosting servers. we also have 3 content writers (-: