# Domain name made of keywords redirecting to main website's page

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

Let's say I have a website called books.com where I sell books. I've read on [Redirecting different domains to your main site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/redirecting-different-domains-to-your-main-site) that it's not a bad idea to register another domain that does a 301 redirect to my website, like booksforsale.com.

Now, say I want to only target a specific category withing my website, like books.com/sci-fi/ so I register sci-fi-books.com and do a 301 redirect.

Would this improve my search rankings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It would not help the rankings of your main website booksforsale.com because your redirected domains would not be authoritive with a 301 alone. You would need relevant, quality back links to those redirected domains to build up back links. The problem then lies with the 301 redirects. 301's do not pass 100% of link juice. So while you can be building links to your main domain and getting 100% of the link juice you're really hindering your own efforts.

The websites such as sci-fi-books.com would help if there were very very few websites which contained those keywords on the internet which is not likely. The keywords in the domain name alone would rank if they were extremely unique. But since that's not likely and Google is taking into considering hundreds of other signals a newly registered domain redirecting to your primary domain isn't going to help much.

You should maybe build up genuine content on these domains and link to your primary rather than doing a 301 redirect. It sounds like you are trying to hurry the process of ranking naturally and this is really cutting a lot of corners. It's not worth the time or money.

Answer (score 0):

It will be kind of a URL Shortner for you, so it may help if people start referring that url on social media and other sites. Again as @Anagio said the help will not be in terms of link juice or SEO but can get some traffic, I won't see a harm in doing that.