# 301 permanent redirect from keyword domain

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

I want to rank for the keyword `widget` with my website `myownwidget.example`.

If I purchase the domain `onlinewidget.example` and make 301 permanent redirect to `myownwidget.example` will it help in terms of SEO?

Comment: This has been asked before, although I can't seem to find a suitable/recent duplicate? Old answers like [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38556/domain-name-made-of-keywords-redirecting-to-main-websites-page) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/redirecting-different-domains-to-your-main-site) seem to be missing the point or not entirely correct IMO?

Comment: Another possibility: [What should I do with a ton of alternate domains? Redirect or use landing pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-should-i-do-with-a-ton-of-alternate-domains-redirect-or-use-landing-pages).  @mrwhite I'm not sure what you think is wrong with some of the answers.  [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/38557) looks pretty close to what I would write about the subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Domain name made of keywords redirecting to main website's page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38556/domain-name-made-of-keywords-redirecting-to-main-websites-page)

Answer (score 1):

If onlinewidget.example **is a competitor** of yours with good rankings, this **will work very well**.

If onlinewidget.example **used to be a competitor** until recently, and the website or domain has been offline/disconnected/unregistered for only a few months, this is very **likely to give you a boost** as well.

There will be **zero impact** if onlinewidget.example is…

- a brand **new domain**
- a domain that was **disconnected for a long time**
- a domain that **changed hands multiple times** and was redirected to multiple domains or had content on multiple topics over the years